# Confused about Lua metatables on page 108 of Programming in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table, metatable

I'm studying Lua, using the book *Programming in Lua, first edition*. I'm having trouble understanding metatables.

This is the code and explanations that appear on page 108:

> ```
> Set = {}
>
> function Set.new (t)
>   local set = {}
>   for _, l in ipairs(t) do set[l] = true end
>   return set
> end
>
> function Set.union (a,b)
>   local res = Set.new{}
>   for k in pairs(a) do res[k] = true end
>   for k in pairs(b) do res[k] = true end
>   return res
> end
>
> function Set.intersection (a,b)
>   local res = Set.new{}
>   for k in pairs(a) do
>     res[k] = b[k]
>   end
>   return res
> end
> ```
>
> To help checking our examples, we also define a function to print sets:
>
> ```
> function Set.tostring (set)
>   local s = "{"
>   local sep = ""
>   for e in pairs(set) do
>     s = s .. sep .. e
>     sep = ", "
>   end
>   return s .. "}"
> end
>
> function Set.print (s)
>   print(Set.tostring(s))
> end
> ```
>
> Now, we want to make the addition operator (`+`) compute the union of two sets. For that, we will arrange that all tables representing sets share a metatable and this metatable will define how they react to the addition operator. Our first step is to create a regular table that we will use as the metatable for sets. To avoid polluting our namespace, we will store it in the Set table:
>
> ```
> Set.mt = {}    -- metatable for sets
> ```
>
> The next step is to modify the Set.new function, which creates sets. The new version has only one extra line, which sets mt as the metatable for the tables that it creates:
>
> ```
> function Set.new (t)   -- 2nd version
>   local set = {}
>   setmetatable(set, Set.mt)
>   for _, l in ipairs(t) do set[l] = true end
>   return set
> end
> ```
>
> After that, every set we create with Set.new will have that same table as its metatable:
>
> ```
> s1 = Set.new{10, 20, 30, 50}
> s2 = Set.new{30, 1}
> print(getmetatable(s1))          --> table: 00672B60
> print(getmetatable(s2))          --> table: 00672B60
> ```
>
> Finally, we add to the metatable the so-called metamethod, a field __add that describes how to perform the union:
>
> ```
> Set.mt.__add = Set.union
> ```
>
> Whenever Lua tries to add two sets, it will call this function, with the two operands as arguments.
>
> With the metamethod in place, we can use the addition operator to do set unions:
>
> ```
> s3 = s1 + s2
> Set.print(s3)  --> {1, 10, 20, 30, 50}
> ```

When I tried to run it, I got the result: `{ union, mt, intersection, tostring, new, print}` instead of the numbers in `s3`. Seems I've printed the contents of the metatables instead. Can someone explain what's happening here? The book describes version 5.0 and I'm using Lua 5.1. Could that be causing this?

Comment: The formatting of your code in your post seems somewhat wrong.

Comment: I've just tried the code in http://www.lua.org/pil/13.1.html and it works fine in Lua 5.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bug in [the code you ran](http://codepad.org/DSncIL43#comment-9Yzx0fPZ), not in the code you've posted in the question:

In `Set.tostring`, line 28, you changed `for e in pairs(set)` to `for e in pairs(Set)` and so it always shows the contents of `Set`, not the contents of the given set.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not it. I've rechecked it, and I wrote Set.print(s3). Any other ideas?

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much! It's the second time I've had such an annoying bug in lua where I misprint a letter and the whole code becomes screwed up. In my opinion it's because lua is case sensitive and at the same time allows using variables without actually initializing them.

Comment: @user2697177, in this case `Set` is initialized. It's not Lua's fault.

Comment: You're right it's initialized globally..while set is initialized locally so I guess it's a different case

Comment: @user2697177 you can use `require 'strict'` so it errors when you use an undeclared global variable. See **[lua wiki - Detecting Undefined Variables](http://lua-users.org/wiki/DetectingUndefinedVariables)**.